# postgresql slony-i replication setup

Tags: postgresql, replication, slony

**Postgresql version: 9.1.2**

**PgAdmin iii version: 1.14.0**

**Operating system used: ubuntu 10.04**

i have searched over the net to install and implement slony-i replication, but i couldn't   find any proper guide to it..., i have went through some guides but i couldn't understand... i am newbie so plz help me with simple steps...

so, anyone can share me step by step guide, to install slony-i and do a test replication..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is [link](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/dev/slony-install.html)  from where you can find simple step to setup the slony-i

Answer (score 1):

Official Slony-I documentation is [here](http://slony.info/documentation/2.1/index.html)